# FTC - composition of function placement determining chain rule?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So I was trying to figure out why, as a practice exercise for myself, exactly these two scenarios of the FTC yield different results.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)\ dt \rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}F(x^2) \rightarrow  f(x^2)*2x$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(t^2)\ dt \rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}F(x^2) \rightarrow  f(x^2)$$

I know something isn't right here, and I think it has to do with the notation, and I feel like the way I wrote my first line is correct but the second line is incorrect. I think also it has to do with the computation of the antiderivative of $f(t^2)$ is different and there has to be an undoing of the chain rule like in u-substitution, so the antiderivative actually isn't $F(x^2)$.

Comment: The antiderivative of $t \mapsto f(t^2)$ is not the map $t \mapsto F(t)$. That's the mistake

Comment: @Cauchy thank you, can you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

First there is a typographical one: it is silly for you to use the arrows $\color{blue}{\rightarrow}$. What you are asserting is that those functions are *equal*. So you should be writing $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)\,dt\color{red}{=}\frac{d}{dx}F(x^2)\color{red}{=}2x\cdot f(x^2)$, etc.

The second error is that the function $x\mapsto \int_a^{x^2}f(t)\,dt$ is not equivalent to the function $x\mapsto\int_a^{x}f(t^2)\,dt$, nor do they differ only by a constant, so it is not clear why you think they ought to have the same derivative.

For example, take $f(t)\equiv 1$, i.e., the function that is equal to $1$ for all values of $t$. Then the value of the first function is $\int_a^{x^2}dt=x^2-a$ while the value of the second function is $\int_a^xdt=x-a$. For this reason, it is wrong to expect that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)\,dt=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(t^2)\,dt$$

Indeed, in this case, when $f(t)\equiv 1$, we get that the derivative of the first function, with respect to $x$, is the function $x\mapsto 2x$, while the derivative of the second function, with respect to $x$, is the function $x\mapsto 1$.

---

Here is the correct way to do the calculation. Let us set $g(x)=\int_a^{x^2}f(t)\,dt$ and $h(x)=\int_a^{x}f(t^2)\,dt$ and assume that the hypotheses of the FTC are satisfied.

Then indeed $g'(x)=2x\cdot f(x^2)$, using the chain rule.

Moreover, with $f(t^2):=j(t)$, we see $h(x)=\int_a^{x}j(t)\,dt$, so $h'(x)=j(x)=f(x^2)$.

**So your final answers, $2x\cdot f(x^2)$ and $f(x^2)$, are indeed correct**; the functions I've called $g$ and $h$ **do** have different derivatives.

Your error is subtle and lies in thinking that both derivatives yield $\frac{d}{dx}F(x^2)$. That is correct for the first calculation, though it would be more precise to write $\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^2)-F(a))$. However, as the user Cauchy says in a comment, the antiderivative of $f(t^2)=j(t)$ is not the same thing as the antiderivative of $f(t)$. The correct statement for the second calculation is $\frac{d}{dx}(J(x)-J(a))$. The FTC says this gives $j(x)=f(x^2)$.